# Python: float number get part before "e"

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point

I am doing some calculation using Python. In a step, there will be array which looks like

```
[1.23e-21, 2.32e-14, 8.87e-12, .....]
```

I just want to get the part before `e..`, i.e., I want to get array

```
[1.23, 2.32, 8.87,.....]
```

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Do all of the numbers have exactly two decimal places?

Comment: @Keiwan No, they are random

Comment: What's this for? By taking the part before the `e`, you're multiplying your numbers by essentially arbitrary powers of 10. It seems like an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one of possibly many solutions:

```
from math import floor, log10

x = [1.23e-21, 2.32e-14, 8.87e-12, 1.51, 1.214e10]

res = [t/10**floor(log10(abs(t))) if t!= 0 else 0 for t in x]
```

Comment: I small corner case you have to take care of is `t == 0`: in that case, `log10` is undefined.

Comment: you're right. I also forgot to care for negative values

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the entries to strings and split them at the `e`. Combine that with list comprehension and you get:

```
numbers = [1.23e-21, 2.32e-14, 8.87e-12]  

result = [float(str(i).split('e')[0]) for i in numbers]
```

If all of your numbers have exactly two decimal places, you could use the slice operator for strings and list comprehension:

```
result = [float(str(i)[:4]) for i in numbers]
```

Comment: This will fail for numbers that are not normally represented in scientific notation; better use explicit string formatting.

Comment: @tobias_k Could you maybe give me an example of a number for which this would not work, so I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: For example, `math.pi` would be printed with 11 decimal places after the dot, or `12345.6` would still have 5 digits before the dot. Using `"%.2e" % x` you get the same number of significant digits for each number, no matter how big.